# Runtime error Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation” from Script task

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

While running the  script task an message box with runtime exception came and package is aborted.

I tried to debug the script by using msgbox in vb and it worked fine upto some point and after that it thrown the exception.

```
Dim SSHClient As New SSHClient()
```

My code uses SSH.client connection which is used to access sftp file share.I am importing  the DLL

```
Imports Xceed.SSH.Client
```

Everytime I run the same exception is coming..need some help In this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the exception is thrown because the reference is not found at runtime, you have to assign this reference to the [Global Cache assembly using GACUTIL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-install-an-assembly-into-the-gac) or just copy the DLL file to the following directories:

**(1) .Net Framework dll directory**

```
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v[.net installed version]\
```

*example*

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\
```

**(2) SQL server data tools dll runtime directory**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\[SQL Server version]\DTS\Binn
```

*example*

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn
```

Comment: Thanks for the info..but one quick doubt...the dlls which are there in above mentioned folders were system defined framework dll..so the dlls which we want to add to the folders are application specific...won't it effect the process changes going forward?

Comment: No these are the default folders, where .nrt apps search for libraries. It won't affect anything